# View streaming video with webView

Tags: java, android, webview

In my application, "public void nasaTV (View v)" I'm trying to run a streaming video but is only carrying. I tried to put a youtube link but also just loading.
Can anyone help me?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText editText;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.url);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewlayout);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
}

public void abrirPagina (View v){
    String url = editText.getText().toString();
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}

public void acessoDireto (View v){
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com.br");
}

public void nasaTV (View v){
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.ustream.tv/nasahdtv");
}

private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean overrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        return true;
    }

}
}
```

My Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.luizhmu.aulas_android_webview" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your onCreate:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

And, do you really need to load the whole page? You can just display iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the information but did not work, even is returning to the line "mWebView.getSettings () setPluginState (WebSettings.PluginState.ON);." is deprecated.
I really need an application to perform streaming through webView. In iOS I can run normally. @Holoceo